# Is it possible to display invisible character on chrome's password input

Tags: google-chrome, web

I got following requirements:
1. Display * on password input field on browser to indicate customer the field has a input yet.
2. The echoed password could just be a placeholder which means it has same length with the real one but it's not the plain text. This forbids customer to view the plain text with firebug or by html source.

Now I just replace each password character to ascii 20 (an invisible char). Now this works fine in IE and Firefox. However, in Chrome, the invisible char could not be displayed in Chrome.

I searched google and stackoverflow without any clue. Is anyone know the root cause or any other way to fulfill this requirement.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion or help.

Comment: Why not just use <input type="password" /> ?

Comment: yes, I use <input type="password"/>. Let me illustrate more, we allow blank password set. Also user could type something, click save and if he open this page again, without focus on password field, the password  would not be changed.However, at this moment, the password should be echoed as placeholder to indicate customer that he has set it before.

Comment: I think that set the value of the input element should do the work

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `<input type="password" />` when user types something. When he comes back, you just use 6 '*' to indicate that it is set before. This will be more safer because others don't know the exactly length of the pwd.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. yes, I could set 6 '*' to indicate the value is set before. However,6'*' could be the real password user set. So I could not distinguish whether user change his setting when I set the value back(I use jsf to bind value to bean). And if I set 6 '*', user could also see this value by viewing page source.

Comment: @qiuyun Well, you can check whether the 'pwd' is changed by javascript. If true, you save the new pwd. Else, you do nothing. It's unsafe to explore the real pwd to users.